# Insert cell formula from string using code

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a nested loop that generates a string something like this:

```
worksheet1!E3;worksheet1!E33;worksheet1!E63;worksheet2!E3;worksheet2!E33;worksheet2!E63;
```

I need to pass this string to a specified cell as a part of a formula. The final formula should be like: `=SUM(<string>)`.

I get:

> Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error

My code looks something like this:

```vb
Dim query as String
query = "worksheet1!E13;worksheet1!E43;"
    
Worksheets("example").Activate
Range("A1").Formula = "=SUM(" + query + ")"
```

The error occurs on the last line of the sample code.

Comment: VBA seems right, I'll update the question. You can concatenate string both ways if the variables are the same type, in this case, they are. I'm aware of the last semi-colon in the string but I tested removing it but it seems like that has no effect at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope** this help you.  it **worked** for me. Just using `Comma` instead of `Semicolon`

> ```
> Dim query as String
> query = "worksheet1!E13,worksheet1!E43"
>
> Worksheets("example").Activate
> Range("A1").Formula = "=SUM(" + query + ")"
> ```

**So,** As example, if a user with `French regional setting`, which have the list separator `;` saves a file, then a user with `US regional settings` that had a list separator `,` opens the same file, Excel will adjust the French list separators in the formulas automatically.

**When** writing **VBA**, though, you will need to use the `US-English` conventions for the list separator, which is the `comma`. or you can use `FormulaLocal` instead.

**[EDIT]:**
Instead, you can use directly the local Formula, using `FormulaLocal`

As example ( `SUM` in Frensh formula is `SOMME` )

> `Range("A1").FormulaLocal = "=Somme(A2;A5)"`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually found a solution to my problem, I needed to use FormulaLocal instead of Formula and use my local language to pass the SUM function. This is kinda weird because the Formula function should precisely take functions as English.

Comment: Thanks @MiikaOK, i have Edited the Answers as you mentioned here.